# To generate the number in between range within Pyspark data frame

Tags: pyspark, data-science

Input dataset:

[image]

Output dataset:

[image]

Basically i want to add one more column "new_month" where no will be in between "dvpt_month" and "lead_month" and all other column's values  will be same for the new_month generated in between these months.
I want to do it with pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating an array of sequence between 2 columns and then exploding that array to get rows with all values

```
daf=spark.createDataFrame([(12,24),(24,36),(36,48)],"col1 int,col2 int")
daf.withColumn("arr",F.sequence(F.col("col1"),F.col("col2")-1)).select("col1","col2",F.explode("arr").alias("col3")).show()

#output
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  12|  24|  12|
|  12|  24|  13|
|  12|  24|  14|
|  12|  24|  15|
|  12|  24|  16|
|  12|  24|  17|
|  12|  24|  18|
|  12|  24|  19|
|  12|  24|  20|
|  12|  24|  21|
|  12|  24|  22|
|  12|  24|  23|
|  24|  36|  24|
|  24|  36|  25|
|  24|  36|  26|
|  24|  36|  27|
|  24|  36|  28|
|  24|  36|  29|
|  24|  36|  30|
|  24|  36|  31|
+----+----+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Edit - sequence is available in spark version >=2.4.0. in earlier version can try to use range or map to generate similar array